# List comprehension in Python?

Tags: python

I have this list :

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

I want to delete each element from the list. This is how I'm doing.

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    del a[0]
```

Can I use list comprehension in this? such as `del a[0] for i in range(0,len(a))`

Comment: Why don't you just `del(a)`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Because that does something else?

Comment: I know I can do that as well. But this is just a demo example. I basically want to learn list comprehension. So how can I use list comprehension in this particular example?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Then the complete list has gone. `del a[:]` would be the way to go.

Comment: @python-coder Using a list comprehension for this makes no sense. The only way I can think of is to use a LC with a side-effect: `[a.pop() for _ in xrange(len(a))]`. But again, this creates an unnecessary list in memory.

Comment: List comprehensions are used to create lists, and this is a poor use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehensions are for creating lists, not destroying them. They are not the right tool for this job.

If you want to clear the contents of a list, the quickest way is

```
del a[:]
```

This is a slice deletion. The omitted beginning and ending points default to the start and end of the list.

Note that frequently, it's better to just replace the list with a new one:

```
a = []
```

This works even if `a` didn't already exist, and modifications to the new list won't interfere with any other parts of the code that needed the old list. These attributes are often, though not always, desirable.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't usually do this with a loop at all. To clear an existing list, use `a[:] = []`.

Comment: I like this one, I belive its more explicit than what I would have suggested `a = []`

Comment: It also actually alters the object that `a` refers to instead of creating a new one and re-binding `a` to the new one. Consider `a=[1,2,3]; b=a; a=[]` versus `a=[1,2,3]; b=a; a[:]=[]`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot `del` components in a list comprehension. Why would you want to do that in the first place? A list comprehension is for *creating* a list, not for modifying.

You can replace the list with a different one created with a list comprehension.

The reason is that a list comprehension needs an expression. But `del` is a statement.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension (coming from functional programming, where nothing is ever mutated) is for building lists. Since it appears you want to clear out the elements of an existing list (and not creating a new list with only some of the elements etc.), list comprehension is not the right tool.

That said, list comprehension *can* be abused to do it:

```
[a.pop() for i in range(len(a))]
```

NOTE: This is a bad idea (since it uses list comprehenstion for something completely different than what it is intended for) and I would strongly recommend you do not use it.